# recurrence - Iteration method T(n)=T(n-a)+n

Tags: recurrence-relation

I really need help to solve the following: T(n)=T(n-a)+n where a is a constant greather or equal 1.

So I started to iterate 
T(n)=T(n-a)+n 
    =T(((n-a)+n)-a)+n 
    =T(3n-3a)+n 
    =T(((3n-3a)+n)-a)+n 
    =T(4n-4a)+n

this brings me to the Basic: T(kn-ka)+n.

Is it right ? I am not sure how to solve such Terms with a constant ?
thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let's solve the case $a = 1$; I'll leave the generalization to you:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= n + T(n-1) \\ &=
n + (n-1) + T(n-2) \\ &=
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + T(n-3) \\ &= \cdots \\ &=
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + \cdots + (1) + T(0) \\ &=
\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + T(0).
\end{align*}
$$
In the general case, if $n = ma$ then you'll get $am(m+1)/2 + T(0) \approx n^2/(2a) + T(0)$.

Comment: Hi! First of all thanks for your Response! :) I solved the case when a = 1 but due to the reason that a can be 2, 3 ... I don´t think that it is right ? My solution for the case that a = 1 Looks like:

Comment: T(n) = T(n-1) + n / (n-1) It step
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + (n-1)  / (n-2) It step
T(n-2) = T(n-3) + (n-2) --> 
T(n) = T(n-2) + (n-1) + n
T(n) = T(n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n
The base =  T(k-a) + kn - 1/2(k(k-1))

Comment: The same method works for any constant $a$. Keep trying and you'll get my formula eventually. You can even get a formula when $n$ is not a multiple of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay :) let´s try again.

T(n) = T(n – a) + n / a=1

1. T(n) = T(n-1) + n /Iterationstep
2. T(n-1) = T(n-2) + (n-1)  / (n-2) Iterationstep
3. T(n-2) = T(n-3) + (n-2)

-> T(n-1), T(n-2) in T(n):

T(n) = T(n-2) + (n-1) + n

T(n) = T(n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n

Base= T(k-a) + kn – ½(k(k-1))

n - k =1 --> T(1)

T(n) = T(1) + (n-1)n - (n-1)(n-2)/2

(n(n+1))/2= Ω (n2)

So this is my solution for a = 1 I think/hope it is right ?!